# how to store computation inside of parfor loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm using parfor loop and I want to save the result of computation, but unfortunately I was not successful. Here is my effort. Would someone can help me with this?

```
    In_Fold_Error=[];

    parfor k=1:length(gamma)

        for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)

% bLOCKS OF CODE

            % Do the prediction on Kth f;old and compute the error
            tmp=zeros(nfolds,Num_Tasks);
            % coff
            sum((A_Test*coff-Y_Test).^2) ./ size(A_Test,1)
            tmp(1,1:end)=sum((A_Test*coff-Y_Test).^2) ./ size(A_Test,1);
            tmp;
            In_Fold_Error(:,Fold)=tmp;
        end
    end
```

the error that I get is for: *valid indices for `In_Fold_Error` is restricted in parfor loops.*

Is there anyway to save tmp of all iterations and use it later on?

Comment: Consider reading the documentation about [sliced variables](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html?refresh=true)

Answer (score 2):

To minimize data transfer overhead, `parfor` loops slice variables into bits and hand each loop iteration only the information it really needs. If you assign `In_Fold_Error` as empty, `parfor` does not think this is a reasonably sliceable variable.

If, instead, you write `In_Fold_Error = NaN(numRows, numFolds)` in the beginning of your code (which is good practice, anyway), each fold will get one column of `In_Fold_Error` to work with and can assign the result appropriately.